# Permutation of nonnegative integers applied to the numbers $n$ whose binary expansion does not begin with $11$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ is [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120), number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$) and
$$n=2^{b_1}(1+2^{b_2+1}(1+2^{b_3+1}(1+\cdots(1+2^{b_{\operatorname{wt}(n)-1}+1}(1+2^{b_{\operatorname{wt}(n)}+1})))))$$
Then we have an integer sequence given by
$$a(n)=2^{b_1}((-1)^{\operatorname{wt}(n)-2}+2^{b_2+1}((-1)^{\operatorname{wt}(n)-3}+2^{b_3+1}(1+\cdots(-1+2^{b_{\operatorname{wt}(n)-1}+1}(1+2^{b_{\operatorname{wt}(n)}+1})))))$$
I conjecture that
$$a(2n+1)=b(c(n)+2)$$
Here $b(n)$ is [A004761](https://oeis.org/A004761), the numbers $n$ whose binary expansion does not begin with $11$. The sequence begins
$$0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36$$
The offset is $1$, so $b(1)=0$.

Also $c(n)$ is [A233280](https://oeis.org/A233280), permutation of nonnegative integers. The sequence begins
$$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 11, 10, 14, 15, 13, 12, 16, 17, 19, 18, 22$$
The offset is $0$, so $c(0)=0$.

Is there a way to prove it?